# Can't find private function for sklearn (LocalOutlierFactor) in reticulate

Tags: python, r, sklearn-pandas, reticulate, private-functions

I tried to add a part of a python code to my R Script. Unfortunately it seems that I can't use a private function for the LocalOutlierFactor in R:

```
# Sample Data
n <- 5000
n_outlier <- .05 * n

set.seed(11212)
inlier <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n, mean = c(0,0))
outlier <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n_outlier, mean = c(20, 20))
testdata <- rbind(inlier, outlier)
smp_size <- floor(0.5 * nrow(testdata))
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(testdata)), size = smp_size)
train_lof <-as.data.frame(testdata[train_ind, ])
test_lof <- as.data.frame(testdata[-train_ind, ])

sklearn.neighbors <- import("sklearn.neighbors")

lof1 <- sklearn.neighbors$LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=15)
lof1$fit(train_lof)
```

Now I want to predict for `test_lof` with help of the private function `_decision_function` from LocalOutlierFactor:

```
lof1$_decision_function(test_lof)
```

Unfortunately there is not such a function available when using reticulate (in Python the function is there). Does anyone know how to use private functions from reticulate and can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[[` to access those fields/functions. `lof1[['_decision_function']]` should give you what you want.